# Library for converting native2ascii and vice versa

Tags: java, ascii

I'm searching for a library (Apache / BSD / EPL licensed) to convert native text to ASCII using \u for characters not available in ASCII (basically what java.util.Properties does).

I had a look and there don't seem to be any readily available libraries. I found:

- JDK, tools.jar, [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html)
- Properties.saveConvert() (private method)
- http://www.koders.com/java/fidD26ED81BEBE41932C405904AD53AEE8459BB8509.aspx (GPL)

Is anyone aware of a library under the above stated licenses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with an CharsetEncoder. You have to read the 'native' Text with the correct encoding to unicode. Than you can use an 'US-ASCII'-encoder to detect, which characters are to be translated into unicode escapes.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

import org.junit.Test;

public class EncodeToEscapes {

@Test
public void testEncoding() {
    final String src = "Hallo äöü"; // this has to be read with the right encoding
    final CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder();
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Character character : src.toCharArray()) {
        if (asciiEncoder.canEncode(character)) {
            result.append(character);
        } else {
            result.append("\\u");
            result.append(Integer.toHexString(0x10000 | character).substring(1).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
 }
}
```

Additionally org.apache.commons:commons-lang contains StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() which can escape and unescape native strings.

Comment: Thx, that's another approach. What I still can't believe that this hasn't already been done in any other available library. Additionally the other way round is also to be considered.

Comment: You could use StringEscapeUtils from apache commons: System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Halloäöü")); There's also an corresponding unescapeJava. Can be found here: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: Thank you, Andreas. StringEscapeUtils did exactly what I was looking for. It seems to me that this would also be a good answer to the question posed.

Answer (score 6):

Try this piece of code from Apache commons-lang:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("ایران زیبای من");
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\u0627\u06CC\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0632\u06CC\u0628\u0627\u06CC \u0645\u0646");
```

Comment: It also escapes quotes, This may be an unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I like the sentence :)