# native2ascii use to detect the special characters in property file in my application

Tags: java, maven

I have few property files like somefile*.properties which contain few special characters, which are accidentally typed. I want to detect these special characters using native2ascii. Please advise me friends. !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library for converting native2ascii and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008989/library-for-converting-native2ascii-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Dear friend, you cannot impose limits to the community on which tool to use for a problem. You are in Linux, Unix I guess. My advice is to run the vi editor, like vi -b filename