# How to convert '(' to unicode(\u0028) in java?

Tags: java, escaping, unicode-escapes, stringescapeutils

I want to convert following string to an escaped String.

I am using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`, but it didn't escape the brackets.

For example:

```
val str = "(안녕하세요.)";
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str))
```

Expected:

```
\\u0028\\uC548\\uB155\\uD558\\uC138\\uC694\\u002e\\u0029
```

Actual:

```
(\\uC548\\uB155\\uD558\\uC138\\uC694.)
```

I want to know the reason why it cannot convert to expected and how to convert to expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal 1-liner that converts all chars to their escaped form:

```
str = str.chars().mapToObj(c -> String.format("\\u%04x", c)).collect(joining());
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/3FRDnv).

Answer (score 1):

- Sharing this:

  [Library for converting native2ascii and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10008989/592355)
- The top answer but also [this(2nd top)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32932829/592355):

  > > `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("...");`

  > It also escapes quotes, This may be an unwanted behaviour.

Means:

- your expectation is rather "exotic"
- behavior could have changed with `StringEscapeUtils` version/namespace/package (??)

#### But no problem

(deleting the if-block + obsolete code (i.e. extra effort) from [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009552/592355))

> ```
> @Test
> void testEncoding() {
>  final String src = "(안녕하세요.)"; // this has to be read with the right encoding (!)
>  final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
>  src.chars().forEach(ch -> {
>    result
>      .append("\\u")
>      .append(
>        Integer.toHexString(0x10000 | ch)
>        .substring(1)
>        .toUpperCase() // or lower case, if you like ;)
>      );
>  });
>  System.out.println(result);
> }
> ```

(+ java updates)

We get:

```
\u0028\uC548\uB155\uD558\uC138\uC694\u002E\u0029
```